# Зачем в nav создавать список?

Tags: html5, список, навигация, семантика

***Тэкс... Первый вопрос на стэке :3***

1. Зачем же все таки создавать списки в nav если можно обойтись без него?
   Разницы между его отсутствием и присутствием я не заметил (за исключением, естественно, стилей)

*На ютубе я смотрел курсы по верстке и кто-то обьясняет это тем, что если вдруг стили не заработают по какой-либо причине, то сайт будет выглядеть структурировано, другие говорят, что если есть объекты похожие по своему типу и идущие друг за другом - это списки и поэтому это все дело нужно заключать в ul>li.*

2. Заключен ли в nav из списка какой-то другой смысл? Или это и правда просто для красивого семантического кода?
3. И как вообще более менее правильно определять что и когда нужно оборачивать в список?

Comment: В список нужно оборачивать список. Ваш Капитан Очевидность

Comment: А спецификация HTML не описывает никакого особенного поведения списков внутри nav, так что можно руководствоваться базовыми соображениями (красивая семантика и всё такое)

Answer (score 0):

У элементов списка возможно и нет никаких доп.свойств. но это лишь сейчас.
А потом вдруг захочется вставить внутрь иконку. или подменю.
или какой-то эффект добавить.
Внутри NAV кроме самого UL>LI может быть её, например кнопочка BUTTON для иконки бургера под мобильные размеры.
И список UL лучше воспринимается с точки зрения SEO.
Но если точно уверены, что нужно простенькое линейное меню - можно напрямую NAV>A и всё, без списка.